# GTK# TreeView sorting and updating rows

Tags: sorting, treeview, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm noob in GTK#, just making my first steps here.. 
Working now with TreeView GTK. Have already read this tutorial: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/widgets/treeview-tutorial/
and make everything I need (adding data from my own class, column sorting with sorting functions)

**But**, according to the Title - I have 2 questions:

1. I need to refresh tree view with new data. And I don't want to "loose" scroll and selection. So the easiest way to clear liststore and fill with new data not works for me (I loose scroll). I need to update rows. I've already learned how to get values from TreeView.Model (iter as my class) - Question is how can I update Iters.
2. Is there any way to disable 3-d column sort position "default". When I click on column I can see Acc, Desc, modes and then some 3-d position (without sorting arrows). Now I make it in that way(remember sorting mode and column, and after refresh I selecting saved mode and column):

```cs
        void Sortable_SortColumnChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a;
            SortType b;
            sortable.GetSortColumnId(out a, out b);

            if (a == -1)
            {

                if (default_sort_type == SortType.Ascending) default_sort_type = SortType.Descending;
                else default_sort_type = SortType.Ascending;
                sortable.SetSortColumnId(default_column, default_sort_type);
            }
            else
            {
                default_column = a;
                default_sort_type = b;
            }


        }
```

But I think there is better way...